# check if a checkbox is checked without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php

I have form on page1.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="F10" id="f10">
<input type="checkbox" name="W10" id="w10">
<input type="checkbox" name="F20" id="f20">
<input type="checkbox" name="W20" id="w20">
<input type="checkbox" name="F30" id="f30">
<input type="checkbox" name="W30" id="w30">
</form>
```

I want to diable a checkbox if another checkbox is checked using **javascript** or **XMLHttpRequest**().
I tried doing it using javascript but it didn't work.

```
if(document.getElementById("f10").checked){
   document.getElementById("w20").disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: that should work fine..!

Comment: is your checkbox checked dynamically..? if yes... how..?

Comment: @Zach Saucier The thing is I can't use jquery in my project.

Comment: @zeee9 The duplicate question has no jQuery in it...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use regular javascript to get a true or false value for checked for example,

```
var isChecked= document.getElementById('elementName').checked;
if(isChecked){ //checked
  //execute code here
}else{ //unchecked
  //execute code here
}
```

or if you want whenever the checkbox check is changed

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('elementName');
checkbox.addEventListener("change", functionname, false);

function functionname(){
  var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
  if(isChecked){ //checked

  }else{ //unchecked

  }
}
```

Comment: This may work, but would be better to determine the checked value from the incoming event, instead of calling the external selector. This way you can watch any element firing the event with a single check. It's possible by accessing `e.target.checked` in functionname (e is the event that must be passed to this function)

Answer (score 1):

can you try my code? it may help you :D

```
<form onclick="checkIfChecked()" method="POST" action="page2.php">

<input type="checkbox" name="F10" id="f10">F10
<input type="checkbox" name="W10" id="w10">W10
<input type="checkbox" name="F20" id="f20">F20
<input type="checkbox" name="W20" id="w20">W20
<input type="checkbox" name="F30" id="f30">F30
<input type="checkbox" name="W30" id="w30">W30
</form>

<script>
function checkIfChecked(){
    if(document.getElementById("f10").checked){
   document.getElementById("w20").disabled=true;
    } else {
  document.getElementById("w20").disabled=false;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a check box is for multiple selections, use radio buttons if you only want one selection available

Comment: No, I want multiple selections to be available . But I want one specific checkbox to be disabled if another is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checked pseudo class but note lack of browser support for IE 8 if that matters to you.
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/